# How do I format my USB

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

My USB wont format, my PC reads that its there but when I try to format it I get an error message that says

```
Error unmounting /dev/sdb: Command-line `umount  "/media/jose/87C5-5F31"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: umount: /media/jose/87C5-5F31: not mounted
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)"
```

and when I try to un-mount it I get an error message that says

```
Error unmounting block device 8:16: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed:
Error unmounting /dev/sdb: Command-line `umount  "/media/jose/87C5-5F31"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: umount: /media/jose/87C5-5F31: not mounted"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are 'confusing' data written to the USB drive. Then it helps to wipe the first megabyte (overwrite with zeros). After that it is possible to create a new partition table and one or more partitions with file systems (alias 'format'). You can do this with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) via the [wipe menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe).

If this does not work, you can try in another USB port and in some other computer. If it is still impossible to format the USB drive, I am afraid that it is severely damaged. See this link: [pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297).